# How to Suppress a Specific SCONS Warning

Tags: scons

I am using SCons in our python project to automate some steps.  We do not use C/C++ in this project, and we do not have Visual C++, or any other C++ compilers installed in our build machine.  However, SCons always gives a warning:
scons: warning: No version of Visual Studio compiler found - C/C++ compilers most likely not set correctly
File "D:\BuildAgent\work\dea9985b7c13c306\CCARModeling\SConstruct", line 14, in

We pinned it down to the line:

env = Environment(BUILDERS = {'RModels' : RBuilder},  ENV = os.environ)

There is no reason Scons should always look for a C++ compiler. Is there a way to suppress this particular warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
env = Environment(tools=[])
```

to disable loading any default tools, and you may want to do the same for the DefaultEnvironment. Depending on which Builders/Tools you actually need, you can give the list instead, like this:

```
env = Environment(tools=['ar', 'textfile'])
```

See also the UserGuide at http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html , especially 7.2.5 Controlling the Default Environment.

Comment: Thank you dirkbaechle.  That was the complete and correct answer I needed!